# 3 seconds to TTFB in CloudFront

Tags: performance, amazon-cloudfront, ttfb

I'm trying to improve the speed of a site and I've noticed that it takes 3 seconds to download some images from CloudFront.

[image: timeline]

To download a 18kb image it takes 3 seconds:

[image: TTFB]

And it's a Hit from CloudFront:

[image: hit from CloudFront]

Can anyone explain why it's taking so long?

Comment: That does seem high.  The IP address that shows up in your browser tools indicates that your request was routed to one of the CloudFront edge locations in Rio de Janeiro.  Were you physically near there the time?

Comment: Yes. Im in Argentina. Tried the same from servers in the US and one time took 2sec also.

Comment: Hi Diego, did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Typo I don't remember. I guess it just went away (or maybe it's still slow but not so much).